# PyQt4 MainWindow object has no attribute

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm writing some GUI and then I want to add text to a listView. Right now I just want to add "hello" to figure it out, and then I will grow it from there.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(584, 461)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(72, 210, 171, 20))
        ....
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), MainWindow.addEntry)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        ....

    def addEntry(self):
        listView.Items.Add("Hello")
```

Then to open it:

```
from PyQt4 import *
import signal
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMessageBox
from inv_window import *
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When trying to run this I get:

```
AttributeError: 'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'addEntry'
```

Any ideas on how I can rectify this? I've tried googling but I'm having a difficult time nailing down a solution

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be on this line:

```
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), MainWindow.addEntry)
```

Your `MainWindow` variable is a `QMainWindow` instance, and so it doesn't have the `addEntry` method which belongs to your `Ui_MainWindow` class.  Hence the error you see.

I'd like to point out a stylistic issue with your code, if I may.  In Python, names of local variables and method/function parameters conventionally start with a lower-case letter.  You have a variable (and method parameter) named `MainWindow`.  When I first read your code I got confused because `MainWindow` looked to me like the name of a class.  I would recommend changing the name of this variable/method parameter to `mainWindow` or `main_window` or `mainwin` or suchlike.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `from PyQt4 import *` for the `main()` method ,you need to import `QtCore` also and `QtGui` it consider as a globle.To make it specific you need to write your main method like:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import signal
from PyQt4 import *
from Ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from inv_window import *
import sys
def main():
            app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
            MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
            ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
            MainWindow.show()
            sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing from the wrong module. Not 100% sure which one but I recommend downloading Pycharm as it helps autocomplete and figure out which modules are available where, without having to manually look it up in your site-package configs each time. I suggest downloading PyQt5. Here is a good tutorial to get you started: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/ Also check out: https://pythonspot.com/en/pyqt5/